# Ensure overlapping (separate) CSS grids rows are the same height as more content is added

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

**Problem**

The code example included shows the desired layout/result. The problem occurs when you add an additional `.product-card` meaning another row is added - I have one in there commented out you can use. Then the overlapping text description stretches to the new height of the product grid and could go behind/over the product cards.

**Rational**

The reason I have separate, overlapped grids is I can't have the description within the same grid due to needing it separate on mobile to display above a products with are in a scrollable carousel.

In the example, the initial layout is correct because I've specify there are two rows with `grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);` but obviously if more products are added this needs to update for the layout to work.

**Question**

Is there away to achieve this without javascript? A way to always make sure the description is the height of the first row/product card? Or would you (and how) need to count the rows and update dynamically?

I know a simple solution could be to duplicate the description and have one within the grid and another outside and show/hide when needed. But it doesn't seem great for SEO having the same content duplicated?

**Code Example**

As I have the mobile layout included to show why I need the markup this way. You'll need to view on a wider viewport to see the desktop layout.

```css
/* Base */

body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 32px 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Mobile */

.products {
  margin: 0 32px;
}

.products__desc {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.products__grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  column-gap: 4px;
  margin: 0 -32px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0 32px;
  scroll-padding-left: 32px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.product-card {
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product-card--story {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Desktop */

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {

  .products {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    column-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    row-gap: 4px;
    margin: 64px 32px;
  }

  .products__desc {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-column: 2 / span 6;
    grid-row: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 64px 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .products__grid {
    display: grid;
    column-gap: 4px;
    row-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-column: 1 / span 12;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .product-card {
    grid-column: span 4;
    }

  .product-card:first-child {
    grid-column: 9/span 4;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

  .products__desc {
    grid-column: 2/span 4;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="products">

  <div class="products__desc">
    <h2>Title Of The Block</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="products__grid">
  
    <div class="product-card">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
      <h3>Product Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product-card">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
      <h3>Product Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product-card">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
      <h3>Product Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product-card product-card--story">
      <h3>Product Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- <div class="product-card">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
      <h3>Product Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div> -->
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```